# Why if $e^{tX},e^{tY}\in G$ for all $t$ then $e^{t[X,Y]}\in G$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Given a matrix Lie group $G$, one way to define the associated Lie algebra is as
$$\operatorname{Lie}(G)=\{ X\in M(n;\mathbb C) | \,e^{tX}\in G\, \text{ for all }\, t\in\mathbb R\}.\tag1$$
Now, we also know that matrix Lie algebras are closed under commutator. So this means that $X,Y\in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ implies $[X,Y]=XY-YX\in\operatorname{Lie}(G)$. Using the above definition of Lie algebra, this means that
$e^{tX},e^{tY}\in G$ for all $t$ implies that also $e^{t[X,Y]}\in G$ for all $t$.

I've usually seen this proven in specific examples of matrix Lie groups. But how can it be proven in full generality? I'm guessing some application of the BCH formula, but I don't quite see how to use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't directly prove that $e^{t[X,Y]}\in G$ for all $t$, but you just show that the Lie algebra of $G$ is closed under the commutator, which then implies the claim by (1). To do this, you observe that for $X\in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ and $A\in G$, you get $e^{tAXA^{-1}}=Ae^{tX}A^{-1}$, so $AXA^{-1}\in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$.

Knowing this, you see that for $X,Y\in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$,  $c(t):=e^{tX}Ye^{-tX}$ is a smooth curve in $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, which is a linear subspace in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ (which is not obvious from (1) but can be proved). But this implies that also $c'(0)\in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ and a direct computation shows that $c'(0)=XY-YX$, which implies the claim.

Comment: thanks. One question: you get to the conclusion observing that $\text{Lie}(G)$ is a linear space, and thus closed under differentiation. However, in this context, how do you prove this latter fact? Because this would amount to show that given $X,Y\in\text{Lie}(G)$ we have $e^{t(A+B)}\in G$. But if to prove this you need to use BCH and expand in terms of exponential of commutators, isn't the reasoning circular (as in, it uses the fact that exponentials of commutators are in $G$, *i.e.* that the algebra is closed under commutator)?

Comment: In the approaches I know, the fact that Lie(G) is a vector space is proved at an early statge. I prefer to start with a definition via derivatives of locally defined smooth curves in $G$ through the unit matrix. Then the point-wise product of curves represents the sum of tangent vectors. fNext one proves that the exponential leads to the same space. The BCH formulea is not needed in any of these steps. I think that many books on matrix groups don't treat BCH at all.